# Reconhecimento de entalhe na tela

Tags: react-native

Gostaria de saber como faço para meu app reconhecer os famosos "Notchs" (entalhes na tela) dos celulares.

Atualmente uso o React Native 0.55.4 em um
Windows 10 64 Bits

Exemplo de um celular com notch abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

**Sem Biblioteca**

iOS

SafeAreaView Aplicável em dispositivos com `iOS` superior ao 11.

Utilização do `SafeAreaView` caso o celular tenha o `notch` ele aplica um layout adaptado para o modelo. [Mais informações e como usar.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview)

Android

Diferentemente do `iOS` o `android` ainda não tem a capacidade de verificar a existência no `notch`.
Porém é possível encontrar o tamanho total do `StatusBar`, dessa maneira:

```
StatusBar.currentHeight
```

Geralmente (não em todos os casos) o `notch` faz parte da composição do `StatusBar`. Com isso você pode determinar um `padding-top` para que fique certo na tela, por exemplo.

Obs:

- Pode acontecer do `StatusBar` estar escondido e não ser possível fazer esse processo.
- O entalhe na tela é conhecido em inglês como `notch`

**Utilizando Biblioteca**

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info) (deve ser instalada) que possui o método `hasNotch()`. O mesmo assim que chamado retorna um valor booleano.

Exemplo de uso:

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
...
const hasNotch = DeviceInfo.hasNotch(); // true ou false
```

[Exemplo Funcionando](https://snack.expo.io/@sant0will/bossy-pastry)